# How to pass string of arguments including quotes to a command without eval

Tags: shell, sh

In this case, I'll be using dialog or whiptail.

The command I want to do is like this

```
whiptail --radiolist 'Example Prompt' 24 80 16 ???
```

Now, for ???, that's series of options in form of `"OPTION" "Description of option" Off|On`

So I'm trying to build a string (ahead of time) that would look like
`"Option 1" "Description 1" Off "Option 2" "Description 2" Off "Option 3" "Description 3" Off`
and so on forth.

How can I pass that including the quotes?

Things I've tried that does NOT work:

```
whiptail --radiolist 'Example Prompt' 24 80 16 ${varWithOptions}
whiptail --radiolist 'Example Prompt' 24 80 16 "${varWithOptions}"
```

What I tried that DID work:

```
eval "whiptail --radiolist 'Example Prompt' 24 80 16 ${varWithOptions}"
```

If possible, I'd like to avoid eval.  Is there any way to do this otherwise?
(Other than calling external commands, I'd like to **keep it POSIX**, and avoid any bashisms or similar.)

I want to stress that the string `"Option 1" "Description 1" Off "Option 2" "Description 2" Off "Option 3" "Description 3" Off` I'm using as an example **WILL** be in a variable, as it's generated during the script execution, so anything requiring me to have that string hardcoded as part of a command will not work.

Comment: @alvits Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you want to avoid bashisms? Bash is widely available and its arrays are exactly what you need. Emulating arrays in POSIX sh is possible but difficult.

Comment: This is part of a script for me to setup fresh installs, which will including making sure bash is present and setup how I prefer.  As a result, I cannot guarantee bash will be present or functional when this script runs.

Answer (score 2):

What you have done without `eval` is pass a long string of text `Option 1 Description 1 Off Option 2 Description 2 Off Option 3 Description 3` when the variable `"${varWithOptions}"` was quoted. Without quotes the variable is subject to word splitting.

What you needed is an array of words where "Option 1" is one of the array members for example. To create an array variable you simply need to parenthesize the words.

```
varWithOptions=("Option 1" "Description 1" Off "Option 2" "Description 2" Off "Option 3" "Description 3" Off)
```

You can then use it with appropriate quoting.

```
whiptail --radiolist 'Example Prompt' 24 80 16 "${varWithOptions[@]}"
```

***Disclaimer***: This will not work on POSIX shells. If you still want POSIX, here's the easiest way, assuming you have no use for parameters, or you have already consumed any parameters.

```
set -- "Option 1" "Description 1" Off "Option 2" "Description 2" Off "Option 3" "Description 3" Off
```

This will effectively set `$1` up to `$9`. You can then run

```
whiptail --radiolist 'Example Prompt' 24 80 16 "$@"
```

Comment: Yes, POSIX is a must here unfortunately.  I can't guarantee a working bash environment prior to the script.  It's a setup script to configure my environment, so before it, anything could be the case, including bash not being present.  

Also, I'm not hard coding the list of options, I'm generating it off of find and printf.

Comment: For the POSIX method, are you limited to 9?  Because my test case is sitting around 144 pieces.  I do use parameters, but by this point in the script (which is in a function) they aren't used again.  If it's not possible to do that way with that many parameters, is there a way to make the eval statement safer? EDIT: I don't mind if I can't reference parameters over 9 with $1, $2, $3 etc.

Comment: Won't let me edit that comment again, but I don't think it's working with that method either,  the string is generated by a find command, not hard coded, so I can't do set -- "1" "2" "3", it needs to come from find. And every way I do that, includes the quotes as literal quotes.

Comment: @Trel - No. It’s not limited to 9. I mentioned 9 because that’s the number of strings in your sample code. Creating dynamic variables shouldn’t be an issue. `”$@“` should be sufficient to use them all at once in your case. If you do need to use them independently, you can use a for loop and shift them.

Comment: I don't know if you saw my last comment.  That method unfortunately isn't working either.  Remember, the `"Option 1" "Description 1" Off` is not hard coded.  It's generated.  Everything I've tried is still including literal quotes in the output.

Comment: @Trel - You have not shown any code relating to that comment. I could show you an example of using anything from `echo` to `sed` to `awk` to `find` that will generate a list of text. But that doesn’t mean it will work for you if you are not writing your code correctly.

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused. I said from the beginning (including in the title of the question itself) I'm working with a string of arguments.  All of my examples, show me trying to attach the variable holding the string to the command.  I have `$varWithOptions`, that's what I need to combine with the whiptail command.

Comment: The `set --` command shows you exactly how to get `$varWithOptions` into `$@`. You are probably better off not building it into a separate variable which then has to be split again (this is less dangerous than `eval` but similarly thorny).  Whatever you were doing to get those values into `$varWithOptions`, do the same directly on the argument list.